# Can't open Nautilus file explorer

Tags: upgrade, python, nautilus, 22.04

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with `do-release-upgrade -d` (as we cannot upgrade without `-d` option yet :( ).

I have an issue,I can't open Nautilus !

I've tried in command line:

```sh
20:18:59 ✗ ~  nautilus
Fatal Python error: pycore_create_interpreter: can't make main interpreter
Python runtime state: preinitialized
```

Here's some information about my computer:

```sh
20:26:46 √ ~  lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
20:26:51 √ ~  uname -srvpio 
Linux 5.15.0-25-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 30 15:54:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

About python on my computer:

```sh
20:28:20 √ ~  python -V
Python 3.10.4
20:28:22 √ ~  which python 
/usr/bin/python
```

> I've tried to re-install Python3.8 & run `update-alternatives` but it didn't work :(

Do you have any idea of what's going on please ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I've found a solution !

As `pycore_create_interpreter` is a function part of the CPython [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/090721721b373c50544d297b56c217cf15992cbe/Python/pylifecycle.c#L638), I tried to uninstall python3.

This process will close the GUI of Ubuntu, so please, switch to a CLI tty (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F5` for example).

Then type:

```sh
$ sudo apt autoremove python3 python3-dev python3-venv # uninstall python3
$ sudo apt install python3-all # install it again
# Then repair your GUI:
$ sudo apt install gnome-terminal
$ sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then you'll be able to switch to your GUI again (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1`), and fully enjoy Ubuntu 22.04 experience (including Nautilus 42 ;p) !